# View table SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to create a view, displaying book titles and number of reviews made to the specific book.

What is the options when the values are not compatible?

Relevant columns in the Books table:

```
ISBN13 PK bigint
Title nvarchar(50)
Language nvarchar(30)
Author Id FK int
Category ID FK int
```

Sample data Books:

```
INSERT INTO Books VALUES (9783852913735, 'Ulysses', 'English', 100, 'January 06, 2002', 1, null);
INSERT INTO Books VALUES (9780195038637, 'Battle Cry of Freedom', 'English', 490, 'February 25, 1988', 99, null);
INSERT INTO Books VALUES (9789178615155, 'Surhörningen', 'Swedish', 195, '2019', 4, null);
INSERT INTO Books VALUES (9789178614577, 'Jag älskar regnbågsenhörningar', 'Swedish', 190, '2021', 2, null);
```

Relevant columns in the Reviews table:

```
ReviewId PK int
BookId FK bigint  -- FK to ISBN13
CategoryID FK
WriterId FK
Date
```

Sample data Reviews:

```
insert into Reviews values(0020, '9783852913735', '120', 11, '2001-02-21');
insert into Reviews values(0021, '9789177836599', '140', 4, '2001-10-19');
insert into Reviews values(0022, '9789178130979', '110', 1, '2002-02-22');
insert into Reviews values(0023, '9789178130979', '90', 8, '2003-09-06');
insert into Reviews values(0024, '9789178614677', '50', 2, '2005-08-29');
insert into Reviews values(0025, '9789178615155', '10', 5, '2004-08-25');
insert into Reviews values(0026, '971019503872', '10', 9, '2009-06-11');
insert into Reviews values(0027, '9780195038637', '20', 2, '2010-11-10');
```

Sample data Categories:

```
insert into Categories (CategoryId, Name) values(10, 'Architecture');
insert into Categories values(20, 'Art');
insert into Categories values(30,  'Astrology');
insert into Categories values(40,  'Baking');
insert into Categories values(50,  'Business Management');
insert into Categories values(60,  'Biology');
insert into Categories values(70, 'Comics');
insert into Categories values(80,  'Computational Science');
```

```
SELECT Books.Title, Books.[Author Id]
FROM Books
INNER JOIN Reviews ON Reviews.BookId=Books.ISBN13;
```

Below is my code for the reviews part, as I want to show the number of reviews per book:

```
 SELECT 
    BookId,
COUNT 
    (BookId) [Reviews]
FROM 
    Reviews 
GROUP BY BookId
HAVING COUNT 
    (BookId)> 1
```

So expected results would be:

```
Title  |   Author  |  BookId   |   Category   |   Number of Reviews
```

Comment: Please show sample data + expected results. Most likely you need to `convert` or `cast` to get the datatypes to match.

Comment: Your JOIN should be on Reviews.BookId = Books.ISBN13

Comment: Why are some of your sample `BigInt` values integers (`9783852913735`) and some are strings (`'9783852913735'`)? Why do some columns not need data types, e.g. `Language`?

Comment: thanks for noticing, been working in a team. will correct this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look in to this query. I created the view and since the category has no values compatible with the books table I used a Left join to retrieve the records which has values in both books and reviews. Feel free to comment on the answer and let me know any other additions or alterations if required. I am happy to assist with.  Thanks for posting Insert scripts and table definitions which gave me fast implementation and testing capability.

```
CREATE view My_View AS 
(
    SELECT 
        [B].[ISBN13] AS [BookId]
        ,[B].[Title] 
        ,[B].[AuthorId] AS [Author]
        ,[C].[Name] As [Category]
        , COUNT([R].[ReviewId]) OVER ( PARTITION BY [B].[Title]) AS [Number of reviews]
    FROM    Reviews [R] 
        INNER JOIN   Books [B]  
            ON [R].[BookId] = [B].[ISBN13]
        LEFT JOIN Categories [C] 
            ON [B].[CategoryId] = [C].[CategoryId]
            
)


SELECT * FROM My_View
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming from your sample query you are after just a count of reviews, you would have something like this (guessing obviously for the other tables you need to join with). Several ways to correlate but a simple count only requires an inline correlated subquery:

```
create view MyView as

select 
    b.Title, 
    a.Name Author,
    b.ISBN13 BookId,
    c.Name Category,
    (select Count(*) from Reviews r where r.BookId=b.ISBN13) Reviews
from Books b 
join Categories c on c.Id=b.CategoryId
join Authors a on a.Id=b.AuthorId
```

Using a subset of the data you added, this query works fine

```
Title                                   BookId     Reviews
------------------------------ --------------- -----------
Ulysses                          9783852913735           1
Battle Cry of Freedom            9780195038637           1
Surhörningen                     9789178615155           1
Jag älskar regnbågsenhörningar   9789178614577           0
```

Comment: thanks, columns are created, but there is no values?

Comment: @EST203 thanks for the edit - the book Id of your review doesn't match the Book Id of the book - what is the foreign key in your data model? Presumably you are missing a column. I suggest you provide several books and reviews as sample data and the expected results, explaining how each book gets its count of reviews.

Comment: I tested with your sample data and everything works as I would expect. Confused by your definitions above and then your data eg `Review.BookId` and `CategoryId` is a `string`, however the query is sound.

Comment: @EST203 still not seeing expected results?